# Javascript - Web Audio API -- Range type Input is not dynamic in Firefox, but it is dynamic in Chrome -added reprex

Tags: javascript, dom, web-audio-api

- The gain controller works dynamically on chrome, but in firefox it does not. I need to re-play audio file for browser to recognize new input value of the range input for firefox. I couldn't figure out why.
- You need to put an mp3 file into "example.mp3" part by the way.
- I'm new in here. Tried the reprex. Sorry if it is not as it should be

[HTML + Javascript]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <button class="button">click</button>
      <input
        class="input"
        type="range"
        step="0.01"
        min="0"
        max="1.20"
        value="0.60"
      />
    </div>
  </body>
  <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
  loopify("example.mp3", function (err, loop) {
    // If something went wrong, `err` is supplied
    document.querySelector(".button").dataset.playing = "false";
    if (err) {
      return console.err(err);
    }

    document.querySelector(".button").addEventListener("click", function () {
      if (this.dataset.playing === "false") {
        loop.play();

        this.dataset.playing = "true";
      } else if (this.dataset.playing === "true") {
        setTimeout(loop.stop, 250);
        this.dataset.playing = "false";
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

[Javascript]

```
(function () {
  function loopify(uri, cb) {
    var context = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)(),
      request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    const gainNode = context.createGain();

    request.responseType = "arraybuffer";
    request.open("GET", uri, true);

    // XHR failed
    request.onerror = function () {
      cb(new Error("Couldn't load audio from " + uri));
    };

    // XHR complete
    request.onload = function () {
      context.decodeAudioData(request.response, success, function (err) {
        // Audio was bad
        cb(new Error("Couldn't decode audio from " + uri));
      });
    };

    request.send();

    function success(buffer) {
      var source;

      // fade-out
      document.querySelector(".button").onclick = function () {
        if (this.dataset.playing === "true") {
          gainNode.gain.setTargetAtTime(0, context.currentTime, 0.25);
        }
      };
      function play() {
        // Stop if it's already playing
        stop();

        // Create a new source (can't replay an existing source)
        source = context.createBufferSource();
        source.connect(gainNode).connect(context.destination);
        // fade-in
        gainNode.gain.value = 0.1;
        gainNode.gain.setTargetAtTime(
          document.querySelector(".input").value,
          context.currentTime,
          0.25
        );
        //gain input assignment
        document.querySelector(".input").addEventListener(
          "input",
          function () {
            gainNode.gain.value = this.value;
          },
          false
        );

        // Set the buffer
        source.buffer = buffer;
        source.loop = true;

        // Play it

        source.start(0);
      }

      function stop() {
        // Stop and clear if it's playing
        if (source) {
          source.stop();
          source = null;
        }
      }

      cb(null, {
        play: play,
        stop: stop,
      });
    }
  }

  loopify.version = "0.1";

  if (typeof define === "function" && define.amd) {
    define(function () {
      return loopify;
    });
  } else if (typeof module === "object" && module.exports) {
    module.exports = loopify;
  } else {
    this.loopify = loopify;
  }
})();
```

[CSS]

```
div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Comment: What does *dynamically* mean in this context? And can you create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for us to debug your issue?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, i was unable to add it on that day, so it took a while but i edited first post with reprex.

Comment: This question has gone unanswered because it's still not clear what is being asked.  What is meant by "range type input is not dynamic"?  It appears the input is being used as a volume gain control.  And the code appears to be based on this outdated [GIT](https://github.com/veltman/loopify) which is specifically for audio looping.  Is there a requirement for "gapless" looping or would a regular audio element work fine too?  The code is really quite messy and could be heavily [refactored](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring).

Comment: @Yogi i'm sorry for the mess. trainee developer here. Yeah, my situation is all about gapless looping, and i was looking for a reference repo to start with web audio api, i found that one (veltman-loopify). It is working magnificent right now as Emiel Zuurbier gave me the solution. But, u said that it is outdated. Is there a more advantageous way to do a seemless-gapless audio loop?

Comment: Yes, @EmielZuurbier did some great research and troubleshooting for you.  Regarding gapless libraries, the one you are using hasn't been updated in 7 years and really is not written very well. I'm no expert with audio, but there are newer and more popular libraries on GitHub.  For example, here is one that was recently updated and that seems much easier to use:  [Gapless 5](https://github.com/regosen/Gapless-5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some experimentation and trying to reproduce your code, I've stumbled on something curious.

Whenever we use `gainNode.gain.setTargetAtTime` we are unable to update Gain value by using the setter `gainNode.gain.value`. I could not find any explanation in the documentation of [`setTargetAtTime`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioParam/setTargetAtTime) or [`value`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioParam/value) as to why this happens.

Fortunately there is a fix without *breaking* the fade-in that `setTargetAtTime` provides.
The solution lies in setting the gain value with [`setValueAtTime`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioParam/setValueAtTime) instead of with the setter.

```
const input = document.querySelector(".input");

gainNode.gain.value = 0.1;
gainNode.gain.setTargetAtTime(
  input.value,
  context.currentTime,
  0.25
);

input.addEventListener(
  "input",
  function () {
    gainNode.gain.setValueAtTime(
      this.value,
      context.currentTime
    )
  },
  false
);
```

Comment: thank you so much for your try. It worked magnificantly, i didn't know there was an alternative to setTargetAtTime as i'm new to development. And because of being new to things, my reprex was a big mess, but you still gave your time, so appreciated sir